# Warning message for Chrome and CDN

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, linux-mint

On our live systems, fellow devs who use LinuxMint and latest Chrome version (Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)), at the time of this writing started to see following message printed in the console:
[image]

Other people with same version of Chrome on MAC don't have this message. The way I read this is that Cloudfront needs to changed something in their SSL Certificate, before the Chrome version M70 is shipped, otherwise Chrome will not load it.

Do I need to be worried, and if so... what should I do to mitigate this potential issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the article linked in the console message:

https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html

Like you, I'm using the "Default CloudFront Certificate". I'm assuming at this point that AWS should resolve this before Chrome issue hits for real. If they don't then you'll need to supply your own certificate via ACM, I'd guess. I'm hoping it doesn't come to that, personally!

Comment: As of today (Jan 21, 2018), I am no longer seeing the message in console and it appears AWS has moved away from the Symantec certs, so this is resolved for now.